# Using flex-row and flex-col with tailwind not aligning correctly using computer and phone

Tags: html, css, flexbox, swiper.js, tailwind-css

I'm having a problem with a website of mine with trying to make it responsive using flexbox and tailwind with flex-row sm:flex-col and it's not outputting in rows only weird columns. Keep in mind I am using Swiper for a slideshow.

Here is my code so far

```html
<div class="flex-row sm:flex-column md:flex-column lg:flex-row xl:flex-row justify-center h-full">
 <div class="background-space sm:w-full md:w-full lg:w-3/4 xl:w-3/4 ">
  <br>
  <div class="swiper-container mr-0 ml-0 sm:w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-2/5 xl:2/4">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <img class="swiper-slide" src="/images/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="swiper-slide" src="/images/2.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="swiper-slide" src="/images/3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <!-- Add Pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="sm:w-full md:w-full lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/4 bg-white rounded mx-10 my-20 px-10 py-5 mx-0 the-form">
  <form method="#" action="#">
   <label for="1">1</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1">
   <br>
   <label for="2">2</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2">
   <br>
   <label for="3">3</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="3">
   <br>
   <label for="4">4</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="4">
   <br>
   <label for="5">5</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="5" id="5">
   <br>
   <label for="6">6</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="6" id="6">
   <br>
   <label for="7">7</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Blokk" id="7">
  </form>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You wrote `flex-col` correctly in the description but the code says `flex-column`. First of all you need to correct that. Then add the `flex` class which sets `display: flex;`. No flex property will work without that.

Also you need to review the notion of "mobile-first". This means that any classes you apply at smaller screen sizes are also applied to larger screen sizes, unless you override them. So, for example, `flex-row sm:flex-col md:flex-col lg:flex-row xl:flex-row justify-center h-full` is the same as `flex-row sm:flex-col lg:flex-row justify-center h-full`.